# Find $a$ and $b$ for $ \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{10} e^{-\frac{x}{10}} dx= \int_b^\infty \frac{1}{30} e^{-\frac{x}{30}} dx $

Tags: integration

I was wondering how (or if) it is possible to find a solution for $a$ and $b$. This comes from a task where I have to calculate the probability for a train $T_{10}$ that arrives every 10 minutes and another train $T_{30}$ that arrives every 30 minutes and the
probability density function for time interval $\Delta t$
between subways is given by an exponential function

$$ p (\Delta t \mid \tau)=\frac{1}{\tau} e^{-\Delta t/\tau} $$

But however, I'd like to know how I can find an $a$ and a $ b$ such that:

$$
\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{10} e^{-x/10} \, dx= \int_b^\infty \frac{1}{30} e^{-x/30} \, dx
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried actually computing the integrals? These functions have very explicit antiderivatives...

Comment: . . . and yet there's an even simpler way than actually computing the integrals. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Which tells you how hard the asker thought about this problem...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : But "simpler" doesn't always mean easier. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_a^\infty e^{-x/10} \, \frac{dx}{10} = \int_{a/10}^\infty e^{-u}\,du
$$
$$
\int_b^\infty e^{-x/30} \, \frac{dx}{30} = \int_{b/30}^\infty e^{-u} \, du
$$
These are equal if $a/10=b/30$, i.e. $3a=b$.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

$$\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{10} e^{-\frac{x}{10}} dx=-e^{\frac{a}{10}}$$

and

$$\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{10} e^{-\frac{x}{10}} dx=-e^{\frac{b}{30}}$$

So it should be:

$$e^{-\frac{a}{10}}=e^{-\frac{b}{30}}$$

$$\frac{a}{10}=\frac{b}{30}$$

Finally:

$$b=3a$$

Comment: Oh I see this is much more straight forward than I thought! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

we ant to calculate the indefinite integral
$\frac{1}{10}\int e^{-x/10}\,dx$ we set $t=-x/10$ so we get $dx=-10\,dt$ thus we get
$-\int e^{t}\,dt$